# Change OpenGL origin

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to change the origin of my OpenGL origin. Pictures will explain:

This is how it is now:

[image: As now]

**This is how I want it:**

[image]

Current code

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,
    (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
 gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
 gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
gl.glTranslatef (0, height / 2.0, 0);
```

after the second glLoadIdentity call

(+ or - height)